# Вывести количество чисел оканчивающихся на цифру 7

Tags: c

Напишите программу на языке Си. Вот полное задание.

> Через стандартный поток ввода пользователем вводятся целые числа. Последним вводится число 0. После того, как пользователь ввел последнее число (ноль), программа должна распечатать в стандартный поток вывода:
>
> - количество положительных чисел, в десятичной записи оканчивающихся на цифру 7.

Я пытался что-то сделать, но все попытки заканчиваются неудачей, помогите дописать код.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num = 0;
    int x = 0;

    printf("To quit, enter 0\n");
    /*бесконечный цикл*/
    while (1) {
        printf("Please, enter number: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &num);
        /*условие выхода из цикла*/
        if (num == 0) {
            break;
        }
        if ((num % 10) &&(num=7)){
```

Comment: `if ((num % 10) &&(num=7)){` замените на `if (num % 10=7){`

Comment: `num=7` вы случаем не `num == 7` хотели написать?

Answer (score 3):

Вот это

```
if ((num % 10) &&(num=7)){
```

стоит заменить на

```
if (num % 10 == 7) {
```

Это и есть проверка *последней цифры* числа.

Comment: Спасибо большое)) Но как вывести количество цифр оканчивающихся на цифру 7?

Comment: Может, количество чисел? :) Заведите переменную-счетчик этого количества, и при выполнении условия увеличивайте ее на 1. А по окончании работы, после выхода из цикла - выведите ее.

Comment: да, количество чисел оканчивающихся на цифру 7))  если я буду увеличивать на единицу , то я получу все цифры , а мне нужны только те которые заканчиваются на 7

Comment: Достало. Получите готовую программу -  https://ideone.com/B7Hdcz - и не говорите ерунды. И запомните - **ЦИФРА** - это просто символ, не может цифра заканчиваться на 7. А то вы как тот ученик, который пишет учителю - "я сто раз написал слово "пошел", и пошол домой"...